# Como usar o copy()?

Tags: php

Estou criando um projeto para importar arquivos, só que preciso do nome do arquivo para usar o "*LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE"*, antes eu buscava uma forma de ler o arquivo temporário automaticamente, até que eu vi essa forma de **copy**.

Estou querendo copiá-lo para dentro do projeto (pasta tmp) para poder ter um nome e local fixo para os arquivos importados.

Está retornando este erro pra mim: `copy() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in`

Segue o meu código:

```
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
$destino = 'tmp/tmp.txt';

$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
   copy($arquivo, $destino);
```

Comment: dê um `var_dump` em `$arquivo` e `$destino`, me parece que algum desses dois não está com o valor esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa linha aqui:

```
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
```

`$_FILES['arquivo']` é sempre um `array` contendo as informações de upload. A função `copy` espera uma entrada com a origem e o destino, e os dois devem ser uma `string`.

Se deseja pegar o nome do arquivo original do cliente, faça assim:

```
 $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']['name']; // pega o nome do arquivo da máquina do usuário
```

Porém, ao olhar o contexto do seu código, se você quer copiar o upload para outro lugar, então deveria usar o arquivo temporário do upload, que é o arquivo real gerado no servidor ao upar um arquivo pelo formulário, assim:

```
 $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
 copy($arquivo_tmp, $destino);
```

Em todo caso, o mais correto é usar a função `move_uploaded_file` para mover um arquivo de upload.

Assim:

```
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $destino)) {
      echo "O seu arquivo foi movido com sucesso";
  }
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui, mas como ficaria se eu usasse o "move_uploaded file"? Eu tinha tentado usar ele também, só que também estava dando erro.

Comment: @Emanoel editei aí. Dê uma olhadinha.

Comment: Deu certinho. Obrigadão mesmo cara!!!

Answer (score -1):

Segundo [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.copy.php)

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "falha ao copiar $file...\n";
}
?>
```

Onde: `$file`é o arquivo de origem e `$newfile` é o arquivo de destino.
Se o arquivo de destino já existir, ele será sobrescrito.

Você está pegando o valor errado para passar como arquivo origem.
Pegue-o assim `$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo']['name']`